# AWS EC2 HTTPS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I recently setup an EC2 instance on my AWS account, then I went to the certificate manager and created a certificate for my domain name that I have connecting to my EC2 instance. I have updated my security group to allow for HTTPS and I have created a Load Balancer for this instance but whenever I go to my site I get a "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" Error.

Comment: Where exactly do you see this `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error?  In some client/browser you are running?  It sounds like that client/browser does not have the root CA (which issued your certs) in its local store of "trusted root CA" certs.

Comment: I had it in chrome but I also got a warning in safari

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the certificate as shown in the browser?

Comment: @Castaglia I would assume that an AWS ACM issued certificate would use a well know CA, which would already be installed in the average modern browser. If it were not an ACM certificate, I would be concerned about root CA truststore for sure.

Comment: Did you install the certificate on your load balancer? Do you use an ELB? Are you forwarding from port 443 on your load balancer to port 80 on your web server? Did you create a Route 53 record aliasing your purchased domain to the load balancer? Can you please share the target URL, or a more detailed description of the error message?

Comment: @BenjaminPorter, I am having the same issues. Have you found a fix on this issue?

Comment: @mark-angelo-hernandez and BenjaminPorter Do you solve the question? Perhaps I can help. Recently I setted HTTPS on Amazon using the Amazon Certificate Manager, Load Balancer and Route 53.

Comment: This has been resolved... It was so long ago that I don't remember how though

Comment: @dr-somar, no I didn't. It will be good if you can post an answer to this issue.